# Android 7 and Captive Portal connection authentication in a checkpoint Environment issue

Tags: android, checkpoint, captiveportal

I'm experiencing an issue with android 7 devices and captive portal.

I will try to explain this particular issue and actual environment.
In our company when someone external(not present in active directory) try to connect on wifi should autenticate him via captive-portal.
Our captive portal is under https://aci.(.etc.).it, but the device seem to can't reach this link, instead it seems to try to reach 
 **connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204**.
Our network environment is under a checkpoint cluster firewall. We have already asked to checkpoint support center, after a check on firewall they confirm us that this issue is an android issue.